# How to say "not affected whether we use A or B" in a short and elegant way?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice, catch-phrases

I want to say:
Whether we use site A or site B in the analysis, we will get the same results. Both A and B are anatomical sites (or topographies) in the human body. So the results of the test will be almost identical whether we use the data from A site or B site. Now I want to express the whole idea in short form using phrases in bullets to be used in a seminar meeting, the nearest phrases which came to my mind are these two:

The test is robust, cost-effective and *cross-topography*.

Or:

The test is robust, cost-effective and *topography-invariable*.

So my question is: what would be the best way to express this idea?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: _Cost-effective and topography-invariable_ is nicely parallel construction and gets the idea across smoothly. _Cross-topography,_ on the other hand, requires a different parse and makes one wonder exactly what's meant -- unless it's a common term of art in your discipline. In that case it makes no difference.

Comment: thanks, indeed, cross-topography is an alien term, better to avoid it, I thought there is a better phrase than -invariable.

Comment: _Invariant_, perhaps?

Comment: _Topography-independent_, perhaps? This is a common way of phrasing things in the field of coding and programming. Plugins, features, etc. can be _OS-independent_ or _browser-independent_, for example. I’m guessing that’s where your _cross-topography_ comes from, too: from things being _cross-platform_ in computing.

Comment: I suspect there's a misuse of the term *topography* here. This [medical dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/topography) defines it as *The **description of** the regions of the body or of a body part, especially the regions of a definite and limited area of the surface.* Which is in line with the more general definition, and to my mind does *not* allow for the word to be used in  the sense of *"regions of a definite and limited area"*. More credible might be *non-[anatomical]-site-specific*, or *application-site-invariant*, perhaps.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, it is an anatomical site, a medical term to refer to sites in the stomach when taking punch biopsies by endoscopy. I am afraid that topography-independent would be misinterpreted as not depending on the site while it does, but not necessarily a specific site when sampling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I didn't get the first part of your comment considering the term, but you enlightened me to use the following phrase, which I guess is the right one to use here: *sampling-site-invariant*

Comment: @JohnLawler, thanks a good suggestion which was supported by FumbleFingers also.

Comment: @doctorate: I could be wrong, because I don't know specialised medical terminology, but the first part of my comment was because the only "medical dictionary" definition I could find gave the definition I quoted. Unless it's used in other ways not covered there, you can't use *topography* to actually mean a specific "limited area of the surface" - according to the definition, it means the *description/appearance/features* of that particular area - it doesn't mean *the area **itself***.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with *cross-topography* is that it is unparallel with the preceding terms. *Cross-topographic* might be appropriate. However, there is also a problem in using the word *topography* see FumbleFingers explanation above. However, since topography is a very specific word and you are addressing people who presumably can understand what it means, I suggest you use ***topographically-invariable***.

> The test is robust, cost-effective and *topographically-invariable.*

Comment: +1 for preserving the esoteric term `topography`, but it would be better if we can integrate the `sampling` into your suggestion of *topographically-invariable*. Any idea how to formulate it?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is 'topographiv-sampling-invariable' but that is a mouthful.